# Enviar a otra página después de enviar formulario sin php

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero que cuando el usuario le dé click a enviar el formulario a la vez se active la redirección a la página de inicio.

lo tengo así:

```
class="contactform" data-version="2" id="contactform"
form mame="contact-form"
imput  class="contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit " Id="contactform1_contact-form-submit" value="Enviar" type="button"
```

- ¿No sé podría ponerle algo en el botón que envíe el formulario y a la vez la redirección sin PHP?

Comment: Hola Header90, te damos la bienvenida al sitio (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre Stack Overflow en español y cómo funciona en general). Lo que has compartido no es código HTML, ni JavaScript, ni CSS. Deberías editar la pregunta para limpiar el código y poner el correcto, así como aclarar un poco el problema, lo que hayas intentado y los problemas que estés encontrando. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para redireccionar a otras paginas con JavaScript hay distintos modos :

```
window.location = "http://nueva-pagina.com";
window.location.href = "http://nueva-pagina.com";
window.location.assign("http://nueva-pagina.com");
window.location.replace("http://nueva-pagina.com");
```

en este caso para poder redireccionar tu pagina despues del "`submit`" del form te diria que hagas lo siguiente.

envia tus datos a server como **peticion AJAX** y le agregas una de las posibilidades elencadas anteriormente como **callback en el success de la peticion**

```
function enviarDatos(datos){
     $.ajax({
         url: "https://tu-server.com",
         type: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify(datos), //array creado con los valores tomados por el input
         success: window.location = "https://nueva-pagina.com", //redireccionamento 
         error: function(e){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
         }
     });
}
```

y al click del boton :

```
$("#contactform1_contact-form-submit").on("click", function(){
     var datos = [];
     //inputs inventados para hacerte ver el funcionamento
     datos.push($("#nombre").val());
     datos.push($("#apellido").val());
     enviarDatos(datos);
});
```

Esto porque al hacer el `submit` del form, ya sea atravez de un `<input type="submit">` o de `document.getElementById("mi-form").submit()`. Lo que hara en ese caso es enviar los datos del formulario a la direccion presente en el atributo `Action` y no te leeria el redireccionamiento echo en una funcion en `onclick, visto que al momento que redirecciona a tu pagina PHP la funcion **ya no existe**. en caso contrario si redireccionas antes del submit del form, los datos **nunca** seran enviados a tu servidor.

con AJAX en cambio, podes enviar los datos a tu servidor y redireccionar a la pagina que deseas, sin preocuparte de los problemas recien descritos.

tene presente que para hacer este procedimiento se necesita incorporar la libreria **jQuery**

aunque la pregunta sea vieja, espero que les sirva.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es aplicar una funcion en el onclick del button

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="red()" />
```

y luego con javascript hacer lo siguiente:

```
<script>
   function red() { 
      location.href = "tu-url"; 
   }
</script>
```